# Extra Button on Woocommerce Product Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a button above the add to cart button on the product category page.

I have found the code for the single product page but not the product pages. Where can I find it?

Comment: You need to add some detail to your question. Start by adding some details as to what you have already tried,

Comment: Are you using child woocomerce theme?

Comment: Can you explain little more what are you trying to do, so I can help you, may send the website link.

Comment: Hello, yes a genesis child theme, just above add to cart we would like another button "Login for trade pricing"